# Какой ключ реестра нужно изменить, чтобы в корзине включить "запрашивать подтверждение на удаление"?

Tags: windows-10, реестр

Какой ключ реестра нужно изменить, чтобы в корзине включить "запрашивать подтверждение на удаление"?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не связан с программированием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь про диалог перед помещением в корзину, а не в самой корзине, то

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

`ConfirmFileDelete` типа `DWORD` устанвоить в 1.
Раздела и ключа может не быть, можно создать ручками

Comment: В Windows 10 такого ключа нету

Comment: @codename0082016. Внимательно прочитайте последнюю строчку ответа.